# How to convert Hadoop version from 3.2.1 to 2.2.0?

Tags: hadoop

I have Hadoop-2.2.0 and Hadoop-3.2.1 in Ubuntu . I tried to install Hadoop-2.2.0 but it automatically uses Hadoop-3.2.1 .

What should I do to be able to use Hadoop-2.2.0 ? I have a project related to that version.

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear how you're getting Hadoop, but don't use apt-get, just download the old version and set it up

http://archive.apache.org/dist/hadoop/common/hadoop-2.2.0/hadoop-2.2.0.tar.gz

> I have a project related to that version.

Same code should work fine if you update your Hadoop client